# Excel VBA - compare three columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and would like some help creating a macro in Excel.

I have a file with two sheets i wish to compare. I need to Compare Sheet 1 Column G (serial number) with Sheet 2 Column C (serial number) and if Sheet 2 Column K = D (Disposed Status) then highlight Sheet 1 Column G a colour.

I have found this code on another thread however cannot get the "and" part to work.

```
**Sub Compare2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2")
For Each i In ws2.Range("G2:G30")
    For Each C In ws1.Range("C2:C50")
    For Each L In ws2.Range("K2:K50")
        If i.Cells.Value = C.Cells.Value And L.Cells.Value = "D" Then
                               i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

    Next
   Next
Next
End Sub**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In different style .. try this ..

```
Sub Compare2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x,y as Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For x = 2 to 30
    For y = 2 to 50
        If ws1.cells(x,7) = ws2.cells(y,3) and ws2.cells(y,11) = "D" Then      
             ws1.Cells(x,7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End if
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help, didn't quite work. nothing is being highlighted

Comment: could you upload your sample file to ge.tt ?

Comment: managed to get it working by expanding the sample (from 30 to 515 and from 50 to 1400)
thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

try nesting another IF statement into it

```
**Sub Compare2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet 2")
For Each i In ws2.Range("G2:G30")
    For Each C In ws1.Range("C2:C50")
        For Each L In ws2.Range("K2:K50")
            If i.Cells.Value = C.Cells.Value Then
                If L.Cells.Value = "D" Then
                               i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End if
        Next
    Next
Next
End Sub**`
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it quite isn't there.
it won't highlight anything at all now even if there is a D in column K